# what is the different between this two?

Tags: solidity, integers

today I have two type

One is like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test{

  function TestVar() view public returns(uint8){
    uint8 a;
    for(uint8 b=0;b<20; b++){
      a=b;
    }
    return a;
  }    
}
```

When I test this function,it would return 19. This is very easy to understand.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test{

  function TestVar() view public returns(uint8){
    uint8 a;
    for(uint8 b=0;b<20; b++){
      a=b;
      return a;
    }
  }   
}
```

But if I put this `return a;` in this place,it would return 0.
Why? can someone tell me the logic?

thanks!!

Edit after @Jaime & @Richard Horrocks answering,thanks for these kindly guy!

So you mean that if I put a {} behind`for(uint8 b=0;b<20; b++)` 
it would run before the for roop?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test{

    function TestVar() view public returns(uint8){
      uint8 a;
      for(uint8 b=0;b<20; b++)
        a=b;
      return a;
    }

}
```

Like this ,I don't use {},and we can find the return a is 19.

Comment: `return a` will return the value of `a` and exit, therefore in the `for` loop the first value for `b` is zero, `a = b` makes `a =0` and then the code exits returning the current value in a.

Comment: Because you're returning from the function inside the first iteration of the loop. The loop is therefore only run once, with `b` (and then `a`) set to `0` (its starting value).

Comment: Thanks for @Jaime & @Richard Horrocks

So you mean that if I put a {} behind`  for(uint8 b=0;b<20; b++)` 
it would run before the for roop?

 
`pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test{
    
    function TestVar() view public returns(uint8){
    uint8 a;
    for(uint8 b=0;b<20; b++)
    a=b;
    return a;
    }
    
}` 

Like this ,I don't use {},and we can find the return a is 19

Comment: The question implies that you have never used any other programming language whatsoever. While this is feasible, I believe that it is not very common (or "natural") to take on blockchain-programming before you've acquainted yourself with languages such as Python, Java, Javascript, or even C, with which you can gather some experience on a more simple environment to begin with.

Comment: Acually,I am a programming noob haha!
So you mean that I can learn other common language before learning solidity?
Or It is still possible that I can learn solidity directly and then learn the other?

Comment: Get your hands dirty with JS or Python first. Even try https://scratch.mit.edu/ to become familiar with code and logic before jumping into solidity.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `{}` then the for loop will only execute the next statement. i.e `a=b`. Then when it completes, the return statement is executed hence you have value of 19.

Comment: thanks for @user3316669

I check that one more time 
So when I remove{} ,it would execute the for loop, and then finds that a=b,and finally return a ,right?

And when I add {} ,it would execute the code in the {},then execute the for loop,right?

Comment: According to your code. You’ve removed the block, {}. So it will execute the next statement which is assigning a the value of b for each iteration of the loop. Hence the return value of a will be the last value assigned by b.